# Using while or for to make a count of numbers PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop, numbers

I need a solution in the PHP programming language, I need to skip numbers 1 in 1 and then successively 3 in 3 then 1 in 1, 3 in 3 and so on ...

Example:
** 1,2,5,6,9 **

Go one at a time then three in three, all on the same line up to number 2924, is it possible in PHP?

My Code:

```
while ($ cont <= 2924) {
     if ($ num% 2 == 0) {
     echo "$ cont,";
     }
     $ cont = $ cont + 2;
```

The code above skip two in two, pair numbers, and i need skip four in four, BUT before add one how i mentioned in text above.... 1,2,5,6,9,10,13,14,17,18,21,22,25....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking odd/even to decide whether you should add 1 or 3 is clever. But I don't think you can shorten it further. Here's my interpretation:

```
<?php
$cont=1;
while ($cont <= 2924) {
  if ($cont % 2 == 0) {
    echo "$cont,";
    $cont = $cont + 3;
  } else {
    echo "$cont,";
    $cont = $cont + 1;
  }
}
```

EDIT;
maybe:

```
while ($cont <= 2924) {
  echo $cont++.",";
  if ($cont % 2 == 1) {
    $cont = $cont + 2;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code might work but you need to ensure that you are staying with the php syntax rules. You need to change your code to:

```
while ( $cont <= 2924 ) {
     if  ($num % 2 == 0) {
        echo "$cont,";
     }
     $cont = $cont + 2;
}
```

Comment: No, the code works, it's only a example, i use google translate to put it here, so get the space..